# Why won't my script work?

Tags: command-line, bash, gconf, syntax

umm my script isn't working and I don't know why, it gives me the error

```
"update1.run: line 187: syntax error: unexpected end of file"
```

Here's my code

http://pastebin.com/4W4AwuY5

I would really appreciate any help you can give, thanks!

Comment: `"update1.run: line 187: syntax error: unexpected end of file"` Where is the line 187 ? Try to add an `exit` at the end of the script.

Comment: Close-voters: Questions about shell scripting on Ubuntu have always been considered on-topic here, and the script provided contains enough information for the question to be answered (as evidenced by the answer).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `fi` at line 18

```
read -p "If you are sure then type DUCKS in all caps. If not type that isn't DUCKS."
if [ "$REPLY" != "DUCKS" ]; then
        echo "QUACK..."
        exit 1
fi
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/title --type=string "Removing ads"
```

Quoting `$REPLY` helps too.

Comment: update1.run: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `gconftool-2'
update1.run: line 18: `fi gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/title --type=string "Removing ads"'

Comment: Double check. You are undoubtedly missing a `fi` there.